# Prove the invertibility of a linear operator.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a vector space, let T be an invertible endomorphism on $V$.

Suppose that $W$ is a $T$-invariant subspace of $V$, define an endomorphism 
$P$ on $W$ satisfying that $P(x) = T(x)$ for all $x \in W$.

Prove that $P$ is invertible if $W$ is finite dimensional.

I wrote a proof without using the fact that $W$ is finite dimensional, I don't see how this is necessary but I'm pretty sure something went wrong.

here is my proof:

let $L$ be the inverse of $T$.

since $W$ is $T$-invariant, it is also $L$-invariant. Thus we can define an endomorphism $f$ on $W$ satisfying that satisfying that $f(x) = L(x)$ for all $x \in W$.

Thus $P$ and $f$ are inverses of each other, thus they are both invertible.

Comment: Please also post your proof

Comment: If $W$ is $T$-invariant, then $T(W) \subseteq W$, so $W = T^{-1} ( T(W) ) \subseteq T^{-1} ( W )$.  If $W$ is not finite dimensional, then it has proper subspaces with the same size (ie bases have the same cardinality), so things can go wrong. But if $W$ is finite dimensional, then you must have $T(W) = W$ by rank-nullity.

Answer (score 0):

The flaw is your assertion "Since $W$ is $T$-invariant, it is also $L$-invariant."

Counterexample: Consider the vector space $\mathbb R^\mathbb Z$ of functions from the integers $\mathbb Z$ to the reals $\mathbb R$.  Let $T$ be the shift operator $(Tf)(x) = f(x-1)$.  Its inverse is $(Lf)(x) = f(x+1)$.  Let
$W$ be the subspace $\{f: f(x) = 0\ \text{for}\ x \le 0\}$.  This is invariant under $T$ but not $L$.

Comment: What does finite dimension have to do with this though?

Comment: See Charlie's comment.